# Can C# BindingSource contain array of strings

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have a very simple app with the DataGridView which has bindingSource assigned to its DataSource property. bindingSource is a BindingSource type which has a Data assigned to its DataSource property. Data has just one property ‘string[] files’. The problem is that when I try to select columns to be displayed, using Visual Designer the ‘Selected Columns’ is empty. Why?
I can't attached the zip file of the tiny project created by Visual Studio 2017 so I am providing the code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsAppTest
{
  class Data
  {
    private string[] files;
    public string[] Files { get => files; set => files = value; }
  }
}

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsAppTest
{
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false. 
    </param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    #region "business object"

    #endregion

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.dataGridView = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.bindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.bindingSource)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // dataGridView
        // 
        this.dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.dataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView.DataSource = this.bindingSource;
        this.dataGridView.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.dataGridView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.dataGridView.Name = "dataGridView";
        this.dataGridView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
        this.dataGridView.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // bindingSource
        // 
        this.bindingSource.DataSource = typeof(WindowsFormsAppTest.Data);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.bindingSource)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion
    private DataGridView dataGridView;
    private BindingSource bindingSource;
}
}
```

Regards,

Janusz

Comment: You haven't shown any code that populates the array..? Also, do you not need to specify the array as the binding source? It's late here so I may just be tired.

Comment: I didn't even get to the population of the the array. My dataGridView is not even showing the table. This is what Visual Designer shows an empty "Selected Columns" property. I would have inserted an image here but I don't now how or if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

To bind to a data grid view, the data source must be a collection:

```
public class Data : List<EclipseFileInfo> { }

public class EclipseFileInfo
{
    private List<string> files;
    private string alias;

    public List<string> Files { get { return files; } set { files = value; } }
    public string Alias { get { return alias; } set { alias = value; } }
}
```

As you wish to display the Files string[] as a combo box in your grid view, we need to add the combo box manually, and also set its data source manually. We can do the first part in the form constructor:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete;
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboboxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboboxColumn);

    Data data = new Data();
    data.Add(new EclipseFileInfo() { Alias = "Some Namespace 1", Files = new List<string> { "File1", "File2" } });
    data.Add(new EclipseFileInfo() { Alias = "Some Namespace 2", Files = new List<string> { "File3", "File4" } });
    data.Add(new EclipseFileInfo() { Alias = "Some Namespace 2", Files = new List<string> { "File5", "File6" } });

    dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
}
```

Then the second part in the DataBindingComplete event handler:

```
void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
        cell.DataSource = (row.DataBoundItem as EclipseFileInfo).Files;
    }
}
```

The final view is like the following:

[image]

Comment: I think we are misunderstanding each other. If you change the Data.css property from string[] to just string:
public class Data
    {
        private string files;

        public string Files { get => files; set => files = value; }
    }
 you will see that Visual Designer immediately start showing column "Files". I am guessing there is nothing wrong then with my Data not being a List, but there is a problem somehow with my Files property being string[] instead of string. I can't see any option to insert an image of what Visual Designer shows.

Comment: I think you are not using the data binding correctly here. If you are trying to display the contents of the array (Files) in the grid view, having a data source (which is not a collection) will show only one record there. I think you are expecting the grid view to show in each row one of your strings in the Files string[], but this is not how data binding works.

Comment: If you just change your data to extend List<string> for example, the only column you see will be "Length" because that is the only public property exposed by string. !!! When your data source is a collection of type T, grid columns are public properties of T, and each grid row shows one T instance. !!!

Comment: I have changed my Data to:

`namespace WindowsFormsAppTest
{
    public class Data : List<EclipseFileInfo>
    {
    }
    public class EclipseFileInfo
    {
        public string[] Files { get => files; set => files = value; }
        private string[] files;

        public string Alias { get => alias; set => alias = value; }
        private string alias;
    }
}`

Comment: So now I have Data class extending List<EclipseFileInfo> and EclipseFileInfo containing two columns Alias and Files. I have assigned to DataGridView.DataSource BindingSource type (variable name bindingSource). To that bindingSource.DataSource I have assigned Data. 
So I expected that VisualDesigner should show two columns to choose: 'Files' and 'Alias', but it shows only Alias. What am I doing wrong? How can I make Files to be visible and to be a ComboBox control?

Comment: If you can tell what you want the grid to display, I can update my answer and put it there. What is the expected output? Files is a string[] and this cannot be displayed in a grid cell. Please tell me what you want the grid to show, what columns it will have and what will be displayed in those columns for each row.

Comment: We need to design our BindingList (Data in your case) according to that. In it's current state, all it can display for an EclipseFileInfo for the Files string[] is "file1, file2, file3" in a single cell for the row, it does not want to do that, so we can have a string property (FileList for example) and can return string.Join(Files, ","); to get that

Comment: I would like the DataGridView column (just ignore Alias for the time being) to display Files property (of EclipseFileInfo class) as a ComboBox listing all values. Each row might contain a different set of Files property for the column(e.g first row might have Files property as strings[] {file1,file2} and the second might have {file3,file4,file5} ).

Comment: I have changed my EclipseFileInfo to contain Files property as concatenated string of files names separated by comma (as you suggested). So now My column that displays file names looks like this:”string1, string2”, however that is not what I want. I would like that column to be a ComboBox that displays those strings as a list of choices.

Comment: This is the first time you mention anything about a drop down. You need a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, and doc says "Combo box columns are not generated automatically when data-binding a DataGridView control. To use combo box columns, you must create them manually and add them to the collection returned by the Columns property."  And you need to set the DataPropertyName of this combo box to your Files property. Note: change Files back to a string[], also, and see if this works.

Comment: See here for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks @Oguz Ozgul. I have read the docs before, but I still can't understand how to implement the ComboBox in DataGridView that displays just a string[] array (Microsoft example is showing an implementation of enum but what I want is an array of strings).

Comment: I am trying your suggestion and follow Microsoft example - I will let you know how I am going.

Comment: Do you know of any example that implements ComboBox in DataGridView that displays an array of strings ?

Comment: OK. I have implemented manually adding the DataGridViewComboBoxCell to DataGridView in the DataBindingComplete handler:
'private void dataGridView_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e) {
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
{
EclipseFileInfo info = (EclipseFileInfo)row.DataBoundItem;
if (info != null)
{
DataGridViewComboBoxCell c = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
c.Items.AddRange(info.Files);
row.Cells[1] = c;
row.Cells[1].Value = c.Items[0];
}
}
dataGridView.AutoResizeColumns();
}'

Comment: When I click on an empty row at the line 'row.Cells[1] = c;' I get an exception:System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.'